# Norm of an operator $\varphi:C[0,2]\to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Given the operator $\varphi:C[0,2]\to \mathbb{R}$ with $\varphi(f)=\int_0^1f(x) dx-\int_1^2f(x) dx$, I have proved that $||\varphi||=2$.

I want to prove that $\nexists f\in C[0,2]$ with $||f||\leq 1$ so that $||\varphi||=|\varphi(f)|$. I see this intuitively, but I don't know how to prove it rigorously. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $|\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx|\leq 1$ and $|-\int_1^2 f(x)\,dx|\leq 1$ because $||f||\leq 1$ and also that $|\varphi(f)|\leq |\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx|+|-\int_1^2 f(x)\,dx|$. Thus, this sum can only be equal to $||\varphi||=2$ if each summand is equal to $1$. But this is only possible if $f(x)$ is equal to $1$ or $-1$ on $[0,1]$ and $[0,2]$ respectively (why? - use the continuity of $f$ here). This in turn implies that $f(x)$ is constantly either $\pm 1$ if it is to be continuous, which clearly does not work.